# What is better process for maintaining android source

Tags: android, git, google-play

I have developed an app which works quite well as per the needs. But Play store has following restrictions for updating an app,

- Same package name
- Same SHA fingerprint
  Also if one losses a key-store or its password then the entire project is in trouble for future updates.
- What if machine harddisk fails and data is not recoverable, even creating new app from git will not help in updating app in future as SHA fingerprint will be different for new app

Is there any way to avoid such problems or is there any way to create new android app with same package name, SHA finger print and digital signature?
These questions have been troubling me for quite some time. I have seen answers that say, it is impossible to update app if one loses key-store so backup it at more than one place. But backing up android app will not help even if package name is same, SHA fingerprint will change once we create new app from old source code or is there any way to avoid this as well?

Comment: To solve this problem you can backup your keystore and password. Then even you loose it, from backup you will be able to sign app with same key.

Comment: @Ramit Yes that can be done, but what about SHA fingerprint? Google Play does not allow us to upload app with different fingerprint even if the package name is same.

Comment: Have you created *.keystore file or not. If yes then by taking backup of this file and reusing it results in same SHA fingerprint.

Comment: Yes I have backed it up but I did not know that, I'll try that. Thanks!!

Comment: Also if two developer using same keystore file then there will not any problem in updating build on play store from any any developer computer. let me know if it helps, I will add this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ramit that's a right answer, I tried it helped a lot, sorry couldn't get back to forum early. Thanks again.

Comment: added as answer, if it helps you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you can backup your keystore and password. Then even you loose it, from backup you will be able to sign app with same key.